# AS7, ClassNotFoundException despite updated sun.jdk module.xml and ear's MANIFEST.MF

Tags: jboss7.x

I need to access com.sun.image.codec classes from rt.jar which JBoss 7 hides by default.
My modules/sun/jdk/main/module.xml has been update to include com/sun/image:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="sun.jdk">
<resources>
    <!-- currently jboss modules has not way of importing services from
    classes.jar so we duplicate them here -->
    <resource-root path="service-loader-resources"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <system export="true">
        <paths>
            <path name="com/sun/image/codec"/>

            <path name="com/sun/script/javascript"/>
            <path name="com/sun/jndi/dns"/>
            <path name="com/sun/jndi/ldap"/>
            <path name="com/sun/jndi/url"/>
            <path name="com/sun/jndi/url/dns"/>
            <path name="com/sun/security/auth"/>
            <path name="com/sun/security/auth/login"/>
            <path name="com/sun/security/auth/module"/>
            <path name="sun/misc"/>
            <path name="sun/io"/>
            <path name="sun/nio"/>
            <path name="sun/nio/ch"/>
            <path name="sun/security"/>
            <path name="sun/security/krb5"/>
            <path name="sun/util"/>
            <path name="sun/util/calendar"/>
            <path name="sun/util/locale"/>
            <path name="sun/security/provider"/>
            <path name="META-INF/services"/>
        </paths>
        <exports>
            <include-set>
                <path name="META-INF/services"/>
            </include-set>
        </exports>
    </system>
</dependencies>
```

Inside my ear, I have META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Dependencies: sun.jdk export
```

And for good measure, I added -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs on startup.

I've tried moving MANIFEST.MF to inside the app's jar that's inside the ear, but didn't work either.
The image processing code is inside a stateless session bean, so it's not inside a war, but it's in the jar in the ear.

I'm not seeing clear up to date documentation on any of the official JBoss documentation sources, or anything practical that offers the solution, or specifically talks about gaining access to rt.jar classes that are hidden by default. I've tried various bits and pieces I was able to pull from forum messages here and there, but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: I found a workaround by adding the sun.jdk dependency to as/ee/main/module.xml. After that, the com.sun.image classes resolve.
But the question remains, where in an ear based app should I have placed the sun.jdk dependency declaration? Putting it in MANIFEST.MF as documented clearly did not work. Perhaps others were focusing on war apps, but in my case I need to add access to these classes from my session bean. Looks like a JBoss bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try add the code below as a dependency in your jboss-deployment-structure.xml file.

```
<system export="true">
        <paths>
            <path name="com/sun/image/codec"/>
        <paths>
<system export="true">
```